# General questions about creating a custom theme Moodle CMS

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, tailwind-css, moodle, moodle-theme

I recently started working with the Moodle CMS and am trying to create a theme that matches the expected design. However, I'm having trouble understanding how the theme system works in this CMS, as the documentation isn't very helpful. How can I create my own navigation template and have full control over the styles?

This is also a general question, as I don't understand where the templates come from. Some are from the parent theme, and what is rendering? Can I disable Bootstrap and replace it with Tailwind?

**Basic theme architecture**

```
├── config.php
├── lang
│   ├── en
│   │   └── theme_dpu.php
├── lib.php
├── pix
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── screenshot.png
├── scss
│   └── post.scss
├── settings.php
├── templates
└── version.php
```